# Make content in a div sticky as the user scrolls past that section?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a div container with some content in it, where the container itself is taller than the content. I want this content to start out aligned to the top of this container (which is currently is), but as the user vertically scrolls past the top of the content, I want the content to "sticky" to the top of the screen as the user scrolls through the vertical height of the container.

Once the user has scrolled past the bottom of the container, I want the content to remain in the container still, but at that point the content would be aligned to the bottom of the overall container.

I'm using a CMS to build this, but an example of my html structure looks something like this:

```
<div class="container" style="height:2000px">
  <div class="content" style="height:300px">
    text, content, etc.
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this doable purely with CSS, or do I need to implement some JS to achieve?

Comment: position: sticky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position: sticky;`  - The element with this will behave like `position:relative` until it encounters the `top` (or whatever side you set)

If it is inside of a `position:relative` container then it will stop being sticky when that container is scrolled past.

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid red; position: reslative;">
  <p>paragaph</p>
  <p>paragaph</p>
  <p>paragaph</p>
  <div style="position:sticky; top:0; background:#CCC;padding:1rem;">I am sticky</div>
  <p>paragaph</p>
  <p>paragaph</p>
  <p>paragaph</p>
  <p>paragaph</p>
  <p>paragaph</p>
</div>

<p>paragaph</p>
<p>paragaph</p>
<p>paragaph</p>
<p>paragaph</p>
<p>paragaph</p>
<p>paragaph</p>
<p>paragaph</p>
<p>paragaph</p>
<p>paragaph</p>
<p>paragaph</p>
<p>paragaph</p>
<p>paragaph</p>
<p>paragaph</p>
<p>paragaph</p>
<p>paragaph</p>
<p>paragaph</p>
<p>paragaph</p>
<p>paragaph</p>
<p>paragaph</p>
<p>paragaph</p>
```

Comment: Thank you - but I need it to end when I scroll past the container its in. Sticky with top:0 keeps it stuck to the top for the rest of the page, no?

Comment: @mickdeez ok, I've updated the answer and the demo

Comment: This worked, appreciate the answer!